# not insert Turkish character Window 8 app to Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have been working with the Sqlite Database on the Windows 8 App.(Sqlite for Windows Runtime)
Turkish character problem when I insert to database.
How can I fix this problem. can you help me?
Thank you very much.
Easy come.

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DbPath))
    db.Execute("Insert Into Stock (Name) Values('ŞşİıĞğ')");
```

i try this but result -> ÞþÝýÐð

```
string a = "ŞşİıĞğ";    
string b = string.Empty;    
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a);    
b= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);    

using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DbPath))
    db.Execute("Insert Into Stock (Name) Values('"+ b +"')");
```

Comment: Show your code and tell people what have you tried so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say your Database doesn't encode your characters the way you're expecting it to.

Comment: Is it a dottless/dotted 'i' problem by any chance? http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html

Comment: @MatthewWatson Watson page not open

Comment: @Nolonar I do not know how can encode.

Comment: @SonerGönül you know, the insert command. It's not worth writing.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the problem is that your column cannot handle UTF-16 (unicode) properly (could be client API). Safest bet is to convert to/from utf-8 on the client side then read/write to database.

`System.Encoding.UTF8` has all the magic.

Comment: i try this but result -> ÞþÝýÐð    

string a = "ŞşİıĞğ";    
string b = string.Empty;    
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a);    
b= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);    

using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DbPath))
    db.Execute("Insert Into Stock (Name) Values('"+ b +"')");